# Magento Router Url - Need Hyphnated Path Name

Tags: magento, path, controller, router

Let's say I use a custom controller to have a url path/frontend name of

```
/customcategory
```

Well, obviously if I have a controller file named 'TestController.php' and indexAction
the url path would be

```
/customcategory/test/index
```

What I am trying to figure out is how I do re-name the Test Controller, or modify the config xml file, so I can have a hyphenated url from a controller file such as

```
/customcategory/test-section/index
```

I know that if I want `/customcategory` to be hyphenated, I can just modify the *frontend* tag in the config file. But the site I am building would benefit from a hyphenated controller route, the part that comes after `/customcategory` with keywords and I cannot get it to work nor can I find an example on google - as crazy as that may seem.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you trying to have a url with the following structure... xyz.com/customcategory/what-ever-hyphnated-path-i-want.html ... xyz.com/customcategory/hyphnated-path-2.html ...etc ?

Comment: Yes. So this way whatever controller file I work with within my custom controller, I can be given full control over that path.

Comment: Take a look at the "Product Tags" section and let me know if this is what your trying to accomplish http://www.contempospace.com/bedroom-furniture/wardrobe-closets/custom-closet-systems/isa-closet-system-shelves-hanging-walk-in-reach-in-closet.html

Comment: YEs, so long as it is coming from my custom controller and not coming from a standard category url. Thanks.

Comment: That not a category url.. that a customization of the product tag module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware you cannot add hypens in the url to match up to a filename.  If you are trying to get a folder structure you can just add more paths to it.

For example if you wanted:

```
Namespace/CustomCategory/controller/test/SectionController.php
```

you could do:

```
/customcategory/test_section/index
```

Comment: Interesting. That's a great point, just add a sub directory in the controller folder. Ok, so it's underscore instead of hyphen. It's good to know that I am able to confirm that it is not natural for Magento to allow the hyphen. I wasn't sure if I was just missing some 'trick' to make it work other than .htaccess magic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is possible using global rewrite in your custom module. You could pass all incoming request for `/customcategory/*` to a specific controller action. But you would have to manage your own route (base on the depth of your url path).

e.g  `www.MageIgniter.com/customcategory/path1/path2`

config.xml

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
      <fancy_url>
            <from><![CDATA[/customcategory\/(.*)/]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[customcategory/index/processroute/tagname/$1/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
       </fancy_url>
    <rewrite>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <tagseo>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <frontName>customcategory</frontName>
            </args>
        </tagseo>
    </routers>


class MageIgniter_Customcategory_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
     public function processRoute(){
           print_r($requestUri = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestUri()); //path1/path2
           print_r($this->getRequest()->getParam('tagname')); // path1
           print_r($this->getRequest())
           // do you custom logic here base on about request path explode('/', trim($requestUri,'/'))

     }
     ...
```

For a working example see "Product Tags" section @ http://www.contempospace.com/bedroom-furniture/wardrobe-closets/custom-closet-systems/isa-closet-system-shelves-hanging-walk-in-reach-in-closet.html

Comment: Very interesting. I will try this out this weekend. I cannot thank you enough for this.