# Magento Shorten the URL of a Module / Rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

On Magento the URL structure of a module will be like this:

```
example.com/[index.php]/:module/:controller/:action/:param1[/:paramN ...]
```

I created a gallery module. The gallery contains several album and the URL for each album is like this (following Magento URL structure):

```
example.com/[index.php]/gallery/controller/view/name/:album_name
```

but I want the url of each album on the gallery will be like this:

```
example.com/[index.php]/gallery/:album_name
```

How can I achieve this? I've tried with .htaccess Rewrite Rule but seems like I got it wrong and it's not working. Here is my copy of Magento .htaccess rewrite rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ## enable rewrites
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    ## workaround for HTTP authorization
    ## in CGI environment
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    ## Rewrite Rule for Gallery Module
    RewriteRule ^/gallery/(.*)?$ /gallery/category/view/name/$1 [L]


    ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

    ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    ## rewrite everything else to index.php
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]    

</IfModule>
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/gallery/(.*)?$ /gallery/category/view/name/$1` that looks okay to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could accomplish this using magento url rewrite in your confix.xml (without the need to use apache rewrite)

```
<global>
     <rewrite>
       <fancy_url>
             <from><![CDATA[/customModule\/(.*)/]]></from>
             <to><![CDATA[customModule/controller/view/name/$1/]]></to>
             <complete>1</complete>
        </fancy_url>
     <rewrite>
</global>
```

Read more @ [do simple url rewrite in magento using config.xml](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/simple-url-rewrite-using-magento-xml)

See my answer @ [Magento Router Url - Need Hyphnated Path Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238428/magento-router-url-need-hyphnated-path-name) on how to access :album_name

Answer (score 1):

If you need to customize routing to be generic for many many routes you can implement a custom router class with ease (ref [`Mage_Cms_Controller_Router` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Controller/Router.php) and [its configuration as an observer [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml#L177)).